# Analyzing each word of a string separately

Tags: java, arrays, string

When I tried to analyze each word of  a string separately, the first word was done well, but I failed for the rest. Help me to correct this JAVA code for right output:

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


            int count1=0;
    int chars_not_x=0 ;

String str = "xyz xyxzghz zyxzz";
    String[] words = str.split("\\s");

for(int m=0; m<words.length; m++){

            System.out.println(words[m]);

            System.out.println("Total characters in the word: "+words[m].length());
    for(int n=0; n<words[m].length(); n++){
if(words[m].charAt(n)=='x'){count1++;}}

           System.out.println("Number of x :"+count1);
           chars_not_x= words[m].length()- count1; 
           System.out.println("Chars other than x: "+chars_not_x);

           System.out.println("\n");


  }} }
```

The output of the code is"

```
xyz
Total characters in the word: 3
Number of x :1
Chars other than x: 2


xyxzghz
Total characters in the word: 7
Number of x :3
Chars other than x: 4


zyxzz
Total characters in the word: 5
Number of x :4
Chars other than x: 1
```

The required output:

```
xyz
Total characters in the word: 3
Number of x :1
Chars other than x: 2


xyxzghz
Total characters in the word: 7
Number of x :2
Chars other than x: 5


zyxzz
Total characters in the word: 5
Number of x :1
Chars other than x: 4
```

Comment: count1 should be set to 0 inside the loop. Now count1 still contains the old values and is incremented with the new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Code as needed-->

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int count1=0;
int chars_not_x=0 ;

String str = "xyz xyxzghz zyxzz";
String[] words = str.split("\\s");

for(int m=0; m<words.length; m++){

count1 = 0;    // Add this

System.out.println(words[m]);

System.out.println("Total characters in the word: "+words[m].length());
for(int n=0; n<words[m].length(); n++){
if(words[m].charAt(n)=='x'){count1++;}}

       System.out.println("Number of x :"+count1);
       chars_not_x= words[m].length()- count1; 
       System.out.println("Chars other than x: "+chars_not_x);
       System.out.println("\n");


}} }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you declared the incremented values in a wrong place and thus worked with them incorrectly. I've changed your code a bit, take a look if it helps you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "xyz xyxzghz zyxzz";
    String[] words = str.split(" ");

    for (String word : words) {

        int xFound = 0;
        int nonXFound = 0;
        String[] chars = word.split("(?!^)");
        for (String current : chars) {
            if ("x".equals(current)) {
                xFound++;
            } else {
                nonXFound++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Word [" + word + "] has [" + chars.length + "] characters, and contains [" + xFound + "] x and [" + nonXFound + "] non-x.");
    }
}
```

- the String gets splitted into words
- each word is split into character Strings which are compared to `x`
- the length of the word is the size of the String array in which the word is splitted

Output:

> Word [xyz] has [3] characters, and contains [1] x and [2] non-x.
>
> Word [xyxzghz] has [7] characters, and contains [2] x and [5] non-x.
>
> Word [zyxzz] has [5] characters, and contains [1] x and [4] non-x.

*Note:* The regex used for splitting to characters I used was `"(?!^)"` instead of `""` because the latter one produces an unwanted blank character as a 0th element in the array (try it out). Splitting to characters or single-character String arrays can be done in different ways though, this is just an example.

Comment: Your change in the code is quite excellent. It has opened another window for me to learn more. As I am new comer, please give me some link to study for  your 'word.split("(?!^)")' part of code.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's called a negative look-ahead.. You can read more info about it and other cool regex stuff here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you reset the count of x for each word:

```
for(int m=0; m<words.length; m++){
    System.out.println(words[m]);
    System.out.println("Total characters in the word: "+words[m].length());
    for(int n=0; n<words[m].length(); n++){
        count1 =0; //**missing** 
        if(words[m].charAt(n)=='x'){count1++;}
    }

    System.out.println("Number of x :"+count1);
    chars_not_x= words[m].length()- count1; 
    System.out.println("Chars other than x: "+chars_not_x);
    System.out.println("\n");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `count1` & `chars_not_x` variable inside the loop or reinitialize `count1` and `chars_not_x` with 0 on every iteration.